# Nodemon not restarting in docker image

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose, nodemon

I am very new to docker and trying to get a working environment for local development. My issue is I can't seem to get `nodemon` to trigger correctly when there are changes. The `nodemon` config works outside of docker so I know that isn't the issue.

Here is what I have in my node app folder.

```
# Dockerfile.local 

FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

CMD ["yarn", "watch"]
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.3
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      # ... my config
  actions:
    build:
      context: ./action-handlers
      dockerfile: .docker/${DOCKERFILE}
    depends_on:
      - "hasura"
    volumes:
      - actions:/./app
    environment:
      # ...my confg
  hasura:
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 9691:9691
    build:
      context: ./hasura
      dockerfile: .docker/${DOCKERFILE}
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    environment:
      # ...my config

volumes:
  db_data:
  actions:
```

The docker image works perfectly when I run `docker-compose build` to build the image, then to run it using `docker-compose up`. Nodemon runs, the other two services run as expect so there isn't any issues there. It just doesn't restart when I make code changes. I have a feeling I am not using `volumes` correctly.

I have a feeling that `- "./actions:/app/action-handers"` is incorrect.

Comment: If the Nodemon configuration works without Docker, then it seems like you're all set?  Run `docker-compose up -d db hasura` to start the dependencies, configure your application to use `localhost` as the database host names in this particular environment, and run `yarn watch` without Docker.

Comment: What OS is running on the host machine?

Comment: I am using a Mac. I have had a thought, is it because when I am using VSCode the code I am editing is actually not the code that is running in the docker container, hence it wouldn't detect the change? If so, how do I overcome this?

Comment: ah yes, that was it! I had to use VScode Remove Development tools to get this working

Comment: Mmm perhaps not... I have now noticed that if I remote connect into the container, I can't use git since the `actions` service is one level deep from the git folder.

Comment: Macos is known to have problems when working with docker containers and volumes. This can be completly FUD in your case. But - It could be that the underlying library (chokidar) that detects filesystem changes, cannot detect the changes properly. maybe try the `-L` flag, see https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1802